# Как правильно унаследовать istream / ostream?

Tags: c++

Ну вообщем цель такова, чтобы в функцию можно было передать либо обьект моего класса, либо же cout , cin.

```
MyStream mout = MyStream();
MyStream min = MyStream();
...
static int UShowTFileList(ostream& out, istream& in);
...
UShowTFileList(cout, cin);
UShowTFileList(mout,min);
```

Очевидное решение не работает. Нет конструкторов.

```
class MyStream : public ostream, public istream {...}
...
MyStream mout = MyStream();
MyStream min = MyStream();
...
-->
Error (active)  E1790   the default constructor of "MyStream" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

Ну и все вызовы тоже.

```
mout << "Hello, world!" << "\n";
->
Error   C2280   'MyStream::MyStream(const MyStream &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Вообщем, как правильно унаследовать istream, ostream ? 
[Исходник класса MyStream.h](https://pastebin.com/uikz28Ut)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, всё что требуется от аргументов `out` и `in` функции `UShowTFileList` --- чтобы у них были операторы `<<` и `>>` соответственно. Возможным решение может быть не наследование `MyStream` от `ostream` и `istream`, а превращении функции `UShowTFileList` в шаблонную:

```
template<typename Ostream, typename Istream>
static int UShowTFileList(Ostream &out, Istream &in);
```